# Write new line in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, text-files

I've been trying to make a VBScript that writes on a new line on the bottom. The only online help seems to make scripts that finds a line to write on, but that is not what i intend. I'm making a log that puts in information on a new line on the bottom of the txt file, without disturbing the previous logs on other lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to a file instead of overwritting the file everytime in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694180/appending-to-a-file-instead-of-overwritting-the-file-everytime-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file for appending by setting the *iomode* argument of the [`OpenTextFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s.aspx) method to 8.

> **Settings**
>
> The *iomode* argument can have any of the following settings:
>
> ```
> Constant     Value Description
> ForReading   1     Open a file for reading only. You can't write to this file.
> ForWriting   2     Open a file for writing.
> ForAppending 8     Open a file and write to the end of the file.
> ```

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.log"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 8)

...

f.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it, using [ADODB.Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado). I usually prefer this because you have a bit more control over the Charset and you can move around the content more easily using Position

```
Const FILE_NAME = "file.txt"

Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adWriteLine = 1
Const adCRLF = -1

dim stream: set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Type = adTypeText
stream.Charset = "ASCII"
stream.LineSeparator = adCRLF
stream.Open
stream.LoadFromFile FILE_NAME 
' move to the end of the stream / file
stream.Position = stream.Size
' Replace Empty with the text you want to append
stream.WriteText Empty, adWriteLine
stream.SaveToFile FILE_NAME, adSaveCreateOverWrite 
stream.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileSystemObject to open the file and a TextStream object to write to it (appending)

```
Dim fso 
Dim txtStream 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile("pathtofile", 8)
txtStream.WriteLine vbCrLf & "hello world"
txtStream.Close
```